# If let statement with CLPlacemark

Tags: ios, swift, if-statement, clplacemark

I'm trying to make an if let statement with the following:

```
if let p = CLPlacemark(placemark: placemarks?[0]) {
```

Currently it's telling me "Value of optional type 'CLPlacemark?' not unwrapped" and instructing me to put

```
(placemark: (placemarks?[0])!) {
```

However if I do that, it then tells me "Initializer for conditional binding must have optional type, not 'CLPlacemark'"

I honestly have no idea how to fix this and could use any help. Thanks in advance

Comment: If you already have an array of placemarks, why are you making a new placemark at all? Just say `if let p = placemarks?[0]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
if let validPlacemark = placemarks?[0]{
     let placemark = validPlacemark as? CLPlacemark;
}
```

You need the ? because placemarks is not guaranteed to have a value